# is there any formula that can be used to duplicate a particular cell specified numer of times?

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on a data currently where i have a list of company names one below the other . eg.

```
 1. A
 2. B
 3. C
```

and many more...
the result needed is

```
 1. A
 2. A
 3. A
 4. A
 5. A
 6. B
 7. B
 8. B
 9. B
 10. B
 11. C
 12. C
 13. C
 14. C
 15. C
```

and so on...
the data is too huge to do this task manually.therefore it would be great if anyone can suggest a formula which can simplify the work :)

Comment: IF one of the below answered your question you should click the check mark by the answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/5,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

To get six repeats, just use ***6*** in place of ***5***

Comment: same result can be achived using `indirect` function: `=INDIRECT("A"&ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/5;0))`

Comment: @Vasily FWIW,  the problem with indirect() is that it is [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection2).  Which means it fully recalculates each time Excel recalculates.  The index function only recalculates when the target data changes.  In a small range this is not important, but if indirect, or any of the other volatile functions are used too much then it will slow down the calculations.  In my opinion Indirect should be avoided when ever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Copy data to a variant Array, and build a new one from it of the required size

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range, v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    n = 5 ' number of entries
    With ActiveSheet
        ' Get existing data into array
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        v1 = r.Value

        ' Create new array of required size
        ReDim v2(1 To UBound(v1, 1) * n, 1 To 1)

        ' copy and replicate original data into new array
        For i = 1 To UBound(v1, 1)
        For j = 1 To n
            v2((i - 1) * n + j, 1) = v1(i, 1)
        Next j, i

        ' Place new data onto sheet 
        Set r = r.Resize(r.Rows.Count * n, 1)
        r.Value = v2
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Gary's student... just a little curious to know about the formula you suggested... just like the function of $ sign is to lock a particular cell or column what is the function of / in your formula ?