# VBA to convert Quarterly data to monthly

Tags: excel, vba

I have Quarterly data witch needs to be converted in to monthly i.e. copy A1 and paste it in to B1,B2 and B3. Than A2 in to B4, B5 and B6. So basicaly 4 quarter readings in to 12 monthly readings. 4 cells in to 12. It's about to convert GDP quarterly readings in to 12 months format for for analytical purposes.

I was able to do this

```
Sub quarter_to_month()
'
' quarter_to_month Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Real GDP %change anu").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("quarter to month").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

but now it probably needs do while loop to get all the results from the quarterly column.
I'm not sure how to do this. Please any suggestions.

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825434/is-there-any-formula-that-can-be-used-to-duplicate-a-particular-cell-specified-n).  there is a vba and formula answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()
 Dim CL As Range
 Dim j As Long
 j = 1
 For Each CL In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
  Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j + 2, 2)).Value = CL.Value
  j = j + 3
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I just found this one "=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/5,0))". It's easy and works fine. I'll try the code too.

Comment: @AlIvon, Try it in temp copy of your worksheet to not loss your formulas